# AWS Elastic IP Limitation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I am trying to figure out the best practices for hosting multiple domains within an AWS account.

For example, lets say I have 20 domains to host. The Elastic IP limitation per account is 5. So I cannot assign an Elastic IP per domain if I want to use the same AWS account.

What would be the best practice for my use case? Should I create multiple accounts which would give me the required number of Elastic IPs? Or should I host a bunch of those sites on the same servers using a virtual host configuration?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Elastic IP limitation per account is 5.

That's just the default allocation. You can [request more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) via support.

It's highly unlikely that you need more than a single IP, though. Name-based virtual hosting is the way you should go. The only reason you'd need multiple IP addresses was if your sites:

1. Needed to support TLS. AND
2. Need to be consumed by ancient operating systems, browsers and devices that do not support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

If you do not have both of the above requirements, you can get along just fine on a single IP.

Comment: So instead of assigning each website it's own EIP I would use Route53 CNAME routing or something like that?

Comment: What kind of setup would I need if I want to host, for example, 10 load balanced websites on the same account? Would it be something like pointing specific domains in route53 to an internal IP (the load balancers IP)?

Comment: You point each domain you're serving to your single EIP. That can be done either via A or CNAME records. In regards to your other question, that's far too broad for comments. I'd recommend looking at some of the AWS examples for high-availability applications and then going from there.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked over the HA examples and know what to do. So sorry, my question is: Isn't each EIP associated with one instance? So if I have 10 load balancers (different sites) how would I route requests to the correct site? Is that where the Name-based Virtual Host apache configurations comes in? Sorry this is just not clear (yet) and I want to fully understand before implementing a solution.

Comment: This is far outside of the scope of this question. If you'd like to ask another question, by all means do so.